bibliography in texstudio
I'm new to LaTeX, and before I used overleaf for this. I'm trying to write an article in TeXStudio and put bibliography in it. I created a bib file, but not sure how to put a bibliography in there. The basic code I have written isn't showing the bibliography in the paper and the citations aren't clickable either.
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{sample.bib} %Import the bibliography file

\begin{document}
Apostol's calculus book \cite{apostol1991calculus}

\printbibliography %Prints bibliography

\end{document}

The output looks like above, where you see it literally just shows the text for the citation nickname and it isn't clickable. There is no reference list there either. How to fix this? My bib file looks like this :
@book{apostol1991calculus,
title={Calculus, Volume 1},
author={Apostol, Tom M},
year={1991},
publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}



Maybe see if https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754 helps

Alternatively, use latexmk to compile your document. That's also what overleaf uses behind the scenes and it will automagically do all the necessary steps.

A document like this needs to be compiled not only with LaTeX (more specifically: one of pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...), but also with Biber. A full compile cycle involves at least LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. (You need not always run the full cycle - small changes in the document not involving citations will be picked by one or two LaTeX runs - but you should regularly run the full cycle to make sure that everything is as intended.) https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains this brilliantly and in more detail. ...

... The already linked https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can configure your editor so that you can run Biber as well as LaTeX. As samcarter says, Overleaf use the awesome tool latexmk behind the scenes, which automatically decides if and how often LaTeX, Biber etc. need to be run and thus can compile your document completely with just one click/command invocation.
